# IE acting strange with Node.contains and Text nodes

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, cross-browser

## Document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id='something'>
            A text node.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

## Script

```
var parent = document.getElementById('something');
var child = parent.childNodes[0];
alert(parent.contains(child));
```

## Results

- Chrome 58 - true
- Firefox 53 - true
- Edge 38 - true
- IE 11 - **false**

I would expect a Node to contain its own childNode. However, in IE 11, if that child is a Text node, this is apparently not the case.

IE has odd behavior with Node.contains and Text nodes. What is the justification, and why does it occur?

Comment: [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains#Browser_compatibility), IE only supports `.contains()` for elements. Edge works properly. You should be able to patch it in IE8+.

Comment: @squint Seems it is a bug
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/780874/node-contains-is-incorrect

Answer (score 1):

> *"What is the justification, and why does it occur?"*

Browsers are very complex and bugs occur in every browser.

Furthermore, I'm *pretty sure* that IE invented the `.contains()` method. If so, it would really only be a bug in the sense that the later standardization of the method didn't follow their implementation.